# Unable to get data at first click in android webview with server communication

Tags: javascript, android, html, httpclient

I am calling this method from JavaScript.
For the first time, it is giving null. But from the second time onwards, the data is coming.
Please help me.

```
@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
public String loadClickedData() {

    pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
            "dialog message", true);
    new HttpAsyncTaskClickedData()
            .execute("http://192.168.0.9/btrepo/btrepo/android_api.php");
    return bdb.getmPosIdData();
}
```

**Here we are getting data through AsyncTask in Android:**

```
private class HttpAsyncTaskClickedData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "get_pos_details"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pos_id", posId));
        return GET(urls[0], nameValuePairs);
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result+" in post ",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        bdb.setmPosIdData(result);

    }
}
```

This method is for **getting data from the server**:

```
public static String GET(String url, List<NameValuePair> pair) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        // receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        is = inputStream;
        // convert inputstream to string
        if (inputStream != null) {
            // jObj = convertIsToJson(inputStream);
            result = convertIsToJson(inputStream) + " ";
            // jSonStr = result;
        } else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am getting data from the server in json string format.
It is displaying attributes with null value like {pos["posid":null, "storeName":null]} etc..

Comment: Can you post updated code here

Comment: check this link

http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/Ajax/How-to-call-webservice-using-Ajax-or-JavaScript.aspx#

Comment: Check this link... Example of post request in javascript

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/02/javascript-ajax-http-get-post.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following function

```
public String loadClickedData() {

    pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
            "dialog message", true);
    new HttpAsyncTaskClickedData()
            .execute("http://192.168.0.9/btrepo/btrepo/android_api.php");
    return bdb.getmPosIdData();
}
```

You execute your `HttpAsyncTaskClickedData()`, and return `bdb.getmPosIdData()` immediately. **(Which will always be an issue for the 1st time)**

The result of the AsyncTask is **only available in `onPostExecute`**, where you call **`bdb.setmPosIdData(result);`**.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // ...
    bdb.setmPosIdData(result); // result is only stored in bdb here!
}
```

The HttpAsyncTaskClickedData runs in the background, and possibly takes some time.
That is why your first call is always unable to get data, as you returned `bdb.getmPosIdData()` **immediately after executing your AsyncTask**.

Comment: Am dismissing dialogue in onPostExecute though result is same like above only.

Comment: You mean `pDialog.dismiss();` inside `onPostExecute`?

Comment: yes. Am dismissing dialogue before setting result to setmPosIdData().

Comment: @harika It has nothing to do with dialogs. Did you read my answer? You are returning `bdb.getmPosIdData()` immediately after you execute your AsyncTask, which will return null, until you manage to get the data and set it using `bdb.setmPosIdData()` inside `onPostExecute`.

Comment: @harika So, the point is get your data using `bdb.getmPosIdData()` only after you have actually stored something in it using `bdb.setmPosIdData()`.  Please accept the answer if it helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class HttpAsyncTaskClickedData extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "get_pos_details"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pos_id", posId));
            return GET(urls[0], nameValuePairs);
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result+" in post ",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            data = result;
            pDialog.dismiss();
            bdb.setmPosIdData(result);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "dialog title",
                    "dialog message", true);
        }
         @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
         public String loadData() {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data+ " hi ",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         return data;
        }
    }

and calling loadData() method from javascript.
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is for get data by using post url in javascript

```
 function jsonPost(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://192.168.0.9/btrepo/btrepo/android_api.php";
var params = "tag=fav_stores&mobile=984989874";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
  alert("hello "+http.send(params));




    }
```